# Custom info window for google maps marker in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on a project which has google maps .I want to create a custom info window.So i created an xml file and did the following in the code:

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00FF7F" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#DC143C"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#DC143C"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

The main class:

```
package com.example.marinamapseg;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    GPSTracker gps;
    double current_latitude,current_longitude;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
                TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
                TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

                // Setting the latitude
                tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);

                // Setting the longitude
                tvLng.setText("Longitude:"+ latLng.longitude);

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;
            }
        });

    }
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            getcurrentlocation();
        }
    }
public void getcurrentlocation()
{
    gps=new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        current_latitude=gps.getLatitude();
        current_longitude=gps.getLongitude();
        //initialiseMap();
        placemarkersonmap();
    }
    else
    {
    gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
public void placemarkersonmap()
{

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(8.505439, 76.971293));


 googleMap.addMarker(marker);

}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

The problem is that when i click on the info window, the outer border of the info window is shown as white an within it my custom xml is shown.I have given fill parent in the xml file but still the white border is shown.How do i remove the white border?

Comment: use your view contents in getInfoWindow not in getInfoContents .that's may help you,

Comment: [customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/)

Comment: Use `getInfoWindow` instead of `getInfoContents` to provide full info window. Make sure to set appropriate backgrounds for root view